# Vue/Vuetify @change doesn't provide full $event object

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using Vuetify in a project and creating an edit-in-place experience. Switching between the span and text field works, and it correctly sends the update to my server. One last thing though before I can call this feature complete, is that I need to determine whether the original value of the input has changed from the new value so that I'm not posting to my server when I don't need to be.

```
<span
  v-if="editableCategory !== `category${category.id}Ref`"
  class="category-header"
  @click="setCategoryEditing(`category${category.id}Ref`)">
  <h4>{{ category.name }}</h4>
  <v-icon small>
    edit
  </v-icon>
</span>

<v-text-field
  v-else
  :ref="`category${category.id}Ref`"
  :value="category.name"
  color="primary"
  dense
  hide-details
  type="text"
  outlined
  @blur="updateCategory(category, $event)"
  @change="updateCategory(category, $event)" />
```

The problem is that when when I console log the `$event`, I get two different responses when testing the `@change` and the `@blur`. The `@blur` seems to give me the normal, full event object and I am then able to compare old and new values correctly. However, the `@change` event simply gives me a string of the new value.

Is this an issue with the Vuetify v-text-field `@change` event not firing correctly (and I should therefore create a Github issue with them?), or am I totally misunderstanding blur/change events (also another very real possibility)?

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look at the events available from the `v-edit-dialog` component - *open*, *close*, *cancel* and *save*. You may also try `@change.native` to see if it helps.

Comment: I'm not using the `v-edit-dialog` here. I actually tried to use the `@change.native` option but it prevents me from pressing Enter for some reason?

Comment: Then you can use a different variable for the `v-model` so that you can then trap the `@keydown.enter` event and compare `category.name` with `temp_name` in order to decide whether to post the new value to server or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blur event usually returns the event from the element attached. But the change event returns the updated value from the input element

but still you can able to read the updated value from the blur event using the below approach

Working codepen here, check the console for expected output: https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/JjjaZOJ?editors=1010

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-form>
      <v-container>
        <v-row>
          <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="3">
            <v-text-field
              label="Outlined"
              placeholder="Placeholder"
              outlined
              @change="updateCategory($event, category)"
              @blur="updateCategory($event.target.value, category)"
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-form>
  </v-app>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
    category: 'category text',
  },
  methods: {
    updateCategory(event, category) {
      console.log(event, category);
    },
  }
})
```

Comment: @J. Jackson, let me know if this answer resolves your issue

Comment: That was the ticket, I knew it was something simple. Thank you!

Comment: late answer.. but perhaps can be useful for somebody else:
you can get `$event` object using `@input.native` instead of `@change`